# Can I Customize my iOS apps PNS Title and Buttons?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have enabled Push Notifications for my iOS app. The device only displays the message I sent though and not the title. Also would be great if I could change the wording on the buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not with ios7. there is only a text body and a unlockAction button